# Noun meaning "a fixedly watch"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not talking about the timepiece, but the act of watching. For example:

> I came back to my post and and continued my [...]

Is there any noun that would fit there?

Comment: Watch. That simple. I returned to my post and continued to stand watch. Or continued my watch.

Comment: The adjective is not needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "a fixedly"? Would ***vigil*** suit?

Comment: @DanBron That's great answer (with a link and definition)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try ***vigil***, [defined by Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/vigil) as:

> ***vigil***, noun: *a purposeful watch maintained, esp at night, to guard, observe, pray, etc*

Thus:

> I came back to my post and and continued my *vigil*

A bit hackneyed, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think *a gaze or a stare* convey  the meaning you are referring to:

To [stare](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Stare):

> - To look directly, fixedly, or vacantly, often with a wide-eyed gaze.
> - To look at directly and fixedly: stared him in the eyes.

- I came back to my post and continued to stare/gaze.

Answer (score 1):

If you are watching for suspicious activity at your post, then **surveillance** is an appropriate word.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surveillance) defines surveillance as:

> the act of carefully watching someone or something especially in order to prevent or detect a crime

So your example becomes:

> I came back to my post and continued my surveillance.

Answer (score 0):

Stare as a noun, as in she gave me a lusty stare.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Madarain. 
Nice to see you here. Answers are nearly always better when they contain a link or two to sources. In this case a dictionary definition would suffice. Check out [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/).